# apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm not recognized

Tags: node.js, installation

I'm following a tutorial and it aske dme to install node.js. Idid it, but it than ask to install the nodejs-legacy apt package. I tried to use

> apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm

, but it it just say:

> 'apt-get' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

-Am I using the wrong commande? 
-How can I solve this?

Here is the tutorial I'm following: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/index#get-started

Comment: are you able to get your node version by this command node --version ? and which OS you are using ?

Comment: Yes I can. I have the 4.2.4 version. I<m on windows.

Comment: if you did not notice this statement in your provided link , In Debian based distributions, there is a name clash with another utility called node. The suggested solution is to also install the nodejs-legacy apt package, which renames node to nodejs. So just check npm --version and you are good to go , you donot need to install the legacy nodejs on windows.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer. It might sound stupid, but your answer is to technical for me to understand it.
-What am I suppose to install?
-Are the line given in the tutorial the line to install the nodejs-legacy apt package?
-when you say: "So just check npm --version and you are good to go", is that suppose to tell me if the nodejs-legacy apt package is installed?
P.S.: I'm on windows

Comment: on windows you don't need to install the nodejs-legacy apt package , so i said just check if you are getting npm --version and if you do then you are fine to follow the rest of the tutorial . and even if you are not getting npm --version you can install it by npm install

Comment: It does! Thanks! That means that means that I can skip the 3 command line that theu give me? (just to be shure)

Comment: yesss that command is for Debian based distribution as you are on windows you can skip them.

Comment: Thanks you. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are on `windows` you do not need to install the legacy of `nodejs` that is for `Debian based distributions` because there is a name clash with another utility called `node`.so you can just **skip** following commands and you will be good to go.

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm
nodejs --version
```